# Implementing logic in Scala for Spark

Tags: scala, functional-programming, apache-spark

So I have some tabular data of the form:

```
node    parent   value
c1      p1       2
p1               3
c2      p1       1
c11     c1       1
c12     c1       1
```

Where there is a tree represented by the node and parent columns (parents could have how many ever children) and the sum of the values of each child = value of the parent. (I mean, this is supposed to hold true but it may not and thats what I want to check)

**What I'm trying to do:**

*I want to check that "sum of the values of each child = value of parent" holds true for each parent given in the input data.*

I am implementing this logic using Scala in Spark so I want to do it functionally.

**What I've done so far:**

The input is a csv file from which I create a dataframe and doing the following gives me, parent => list of children, which is information I know I'll need.

```
tree = fileDataFrame.select(parent, node).map( x => (x(0), x(1)).groupByKey()
```

Similarly I have gotten, node => value, which is again useful info:

```
values = fileDataFrame.select(node, value).map( x => (x(0), x(1))
```

I'm stuck where to go from here. I want to do the addition of the values of all children (using reduceByKey im guessing) but I don't have the set up for that yet since I have parent => list of children, and I need parent => list of values of children.

I am pretty new to functional programming so my brain still thinks in loops.

What would be a good way of implementing this check?
Spark allows the following transformations (http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/programming-guide.html#transformations)

Thanks in advance, any suggestions would be welcome!

Comment: Since your data is essentially a hierarchy, you could solve it as a graph problem, using the GraphX spark library.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am not I understand your question but I think that following approach should work.

First create a data frame with following schema

```
root
 |-- node: string (nullable = true)
 |-- parent: string (nullable = true)
 |-- value: integer (nullable = true)
```

Aggregate data for children:

```
val children = df.groupBy($"parent").agg(sum($"value").alias("csum"))
```

Join with original data:

```
df
  .select($"node", $"value")
  .join(children, df("node") <=> children("parent"))
  .select($"node", ($"value" === $"csum").alias("holds"))
```

Similar solution with GraphX [as suggested](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32121577/implementing-logic-in-scala-for-spark/32123145#comment52136717_32121577) by [@mattinbits](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5142537/mattinbits):

```
import org.apache.spark._
import org.apache.spark.graphx._
import org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD

val nodes: RDD[(VertexId, (String, Int))] = sc.parallelize(Array(
    (0L, ("p1", 3)),
    (1L, ("c1", 2)),
    (2L, ("c2", 1)),
    (11L, ("c11",  1)),
    (12L, ("c12", 1))
))

val relationships: RDD[Edge[String]] = sc.parallelize(Array(
    Edge(1L, 0L, "child"),
    Edge(2L, 0L, "child"),
    Edge(11L, 1L, "child"),
    Edge(12L, 1L, "child")
))

val graph = Graph(nodes, relationships)


graph.aggregateMessages[(Int, Int)](
    triplet => triplet.sendToDst(triplet.dstAttr._2, triplet.srcAttr._2),
    (a, b) => (a._1,  a._2 + b._2)
).map{case (id, (expected, actual)) => expected == actual}.reduce(_ & _)
```

Comment: doing "val children = df.groupBy($"parent").agg(sum($"value"))" results in org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame = [SUM(value): double] and parent info is lost. Doing children("parent") results in error. How do I retain the parent information?

Comment: Also, thanks for the GraphX approach, I will compare the two approach's performance and see which one seems better.

Comment: On Spark >= 1.4.0 group variables are preserved. If there is a problem you can simply add column in the `agg` clause: `agg($"parent", sum($"value").alias("csum"))`

Comment: Thanks, this is what I was looking for! It seems trivial now but I'm very new to functional programming

Comment: Truth be told there is not much functional stuff here. Unless you count [SQL as a functional language](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/q/133980), but I am glad I could help.

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
val nodeParents: RDD[(String, String, Long)] = // ...
val nodes: RDD[(String, Long)] = nodeParents.map { case(n, _, v) => (n, v) }
val parents: RDD[(String, Long)] = nodeParents.filter { case(_, p, _) => p != ""}
                                              .map { case(_, p, v) => (p, v) }
                                              .reduceByKey(_ + _)
val joined: RDD[(String, (Long, Long))] = parents.join(nodes)
```

For your example:

```
> nodes: [(c1, 2), (p1, 3), (c2, 1), (c11, 1), (c12, 1)]
> parents: [(c1, 2), (p1, 3)]
> joined: [(c1, (2, 2)), (p1, (3, 3))]
```